# How to refactor this in J?

Tags: refactoring, j, tacit-programming

Here is a different approach for the Project Euler #1 solution:

```
+/~.(3*i.>.1000%3),5*i.>.1000%5
```

How to refactor it?

Comment: Did you check project euler forum for problem #1?
http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=forum&id=1

Comment: I got this code from there. But the forum is locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[:+/@~.@,3 5([*i.@>.@%~)]
```

usage example:

```
f =: [:+/@~.@,3 5([*i.@>.@%~)]
f 1000
```

or

```
+/~.,3 5([*i.@>.@%~)1000
```

---

```
%~                        = 4 : 'y % x'
i.@>.@%~                  = 4 : 'i. >. y % x'
[*i.@>.@%~                = 4 : 'x * i. >. y % x'
3 5([*i.@>.@%~)]          = 3 : '3 5 * i. >. y % 3 5'
[:+/@~.@,3 5([*i.@>.@%~)] = 3 : '+/ ~. , 3 5 * i. >. y % 3 5'
```

Comment: this is legible for you? I am still trying to figure out each step of the refactoring...

Answer (score 3):

```
+/(#~ ( (0= 3| ]) +. (0 = 5 |]) )) 1+i.999
```

`0 = ( 3 | ])` uses (twice) the trick of verb train (fork) with n u v (discussed at the end of http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/09.htm)

A different way of writing it:

```
+/(#~ ( ((0&=) @ (3&|)) +. ((0&=) @ (5&|)))) 1+i.999
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, using a simple, generic verb

```
multiplesbelow =: 4 : 'I. 0 = x | i.y'
+/ ~. ,3 5 multiplesbelow"0 [ 1000
```

Comment: Nice! How about `multiplesBelow =: 4 : '(#~ +./(0 = x | ])"0) i. y'`? Then you can say `+/ 3 5 multiplesBelow 1000`.