# Finding integers divisible by x an y in J

Tags: j, tacit-programming

Writing my first J program to solver [Euler problem #1](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1) (find the sum of all natural numbers below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5), I got the following solution:

```
+/(+./0=3 5|/n)#n=.i.1000
```

However, I pretty sure there is a clever way of doing it, without using a variable. I tried to rewrite it using a fork, but I don't see how I could replace the expression between () as a verb applied to `3 5` and `i.1000`. Could anybody help me?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557522/how-to-refactor-this-in-j) has a list of other ways of solving PE1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parameterize both values, and thus generalize to a dyadic verb, we'll need to pass each of the parameters through to the places where they're needed. We can focus on the sole point where `3 5` is actually needed by starting with this fork:

```
   3 5 ([ |/ i.@]) 1000
```

In the overall program we need the integers list in two places. The name (`n`) gave us an easy way to use that list in both places. To quickly get the whole program in place, in writing this I initially calculated the list twice:

```
   3 5 ([: +/ i.@] # [:+./ 0= [ |/ i.@]) 1000
```

This succeeds at phrasing your whole program as a dyadic verb, but there are disadvantages to having `i.` appear twice. We can extract it to occur only once by making it the right tine of a fork. The center of that fork is a new, inner, verb.

```
   3 5 ([: +/ [ (] # [:+./ 0= [ |/ ]) i.@]) 1000
NB.              ___________________             new "inner" verb, parenthesized
```

This inner verb needs to receive the `3 5` as an argument so I pass through the left argument of the outermost verb as the left argument to this inner verb. This means Left (`[`) in the inner verb has the same value it had in the previous version, when it referred to the outermost argument. Within this new verb Right (`]`) refers to the list of integers, occurring in the two places that `i.@]` appeared before.

Postscript: As you showed in your comment, `[ |/ ]` simplifies to `|/`

Comment: Thank you. You learned me the cap. My solution is now `+/3 5(([:+./0=|/)#])i.1000`

Comment: It helped my J greatly when I learned that Cap (`[:`) and At (`@:`) are synonyms with different syntax. Cap is part of the syntactic rules of forks, while At involves the syntactic rules of conjunctions. Both compose two verbs. E.g. `[: g f` and `g @: f` have the same meaning.

Comment: The other potential simplification is that it is not necessary to filter the list, we can just find the indicies in the list so we can use monadic `I.` . If we also use a hook to simplify the selection of left or right argument we can write `3 5 +/@I.@(0 = */@(|/ i.)) 1000`